# "name followed by '::' must be a class or namespace name" error in release mode but not debug mode

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019

C++, Visual Studio 2019

I keep getting this error in release mode but not debug mode for lines that use the "filesystem" and "chrono" libraries. I'm thinking that the issue probably relates to how the header files are linked in release mode.

Below are the relevant snippets of my code (ellipses indicate omitted code). The red underline of the error is under "chrono" and "filesystem", respectively.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <ctime>
#include <iterator>
#include <filesystem>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std; 

...

int main() {
    auto startTime = chrono::steady_clock::now();  // ERROR HERE

    ...

    for (auto& entry : filesystem::directory_iterator(AbsPath + PTS_ByIndustry_Path)) { // ERROR HERE
        if (find(TS_ToIncludeNums.begin(), TS_ToIncludeNums.end(), i) != TS_ToIncludeNums.end()) {
            string p = entry.path().u8string();
            PTS_ToInclude.push_back(p);
        }
        i++;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't there be a `#include <chrono>` in there?

Comment: It sounds like the project configuration was changed in Debug but not in Release. In Visual Studio, when you edit a project, you usually want to make sure the project properties window has "All Configurations" selected at the top.

Comment: `The red underline`. intellisense issue? or real compilation issue?

Comment: FWIW, I don't agree with closing this question as a typo. Adding the missing header would let OP proceed, but whatever is causing their build environment to be inconsistent would remain.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed already! In project properties, I was changing the language standard to C++17 for Debug Mode but not Release Mode.

Screenshot:
[image: Screenshot].

Comment: Thank you for coming back and answering your question after finding the solution by yourself!

Comment: @Vedhas Walke I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you didn't import the `chrono` header.

```
#include <chrono>
```

Comment: This doesn't address the discrepancy between Debug and Release, which is the real heart of the question here.

Comment: It is quite possible some other header includes `<chrono>` for debug purposes in debug mode, but doesn't include the header in release mode.

Comment: Good catch. I didn't realize this, but everything compiles fine now, so I believe some other header includes it or Visual Studio automatically adds it in like it does for <cmath>.